# Rational functions between projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I shall assume that a function $f : \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ is **rational** when there are two irreducible and coprime homogeneous polynomials of same degree $P, Q$ such that
$$f(p) = \frac{P(p)}{Q(p)}.$$

I shall say that $f : \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^m$ is rational when it is when composing $f$ with any standard coordinate chart for $\mathbb{P}^m$ each entry satisfy the previous definition.

I shall say that $f : \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^m$ is **regular** when its domain is the whole $\mathbb{P}^n$.

We can easily prove that when $f : \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ is rational and regular then it is constant. This is not the true when the counter domain is projective, for instante, take any projection
$$p_j : \mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^n, j \in \{1,2\}.$$
However, when composing the image of $f$ with a coordinate chart, $f$ must be constant, right? This seems very strange to me, is this thought correct? This seems to show that the image of rational and regular maps are quite particular in some sense.

Comment: The coordinate map $f$ isn't regular though, is it? For instance, the coordinate map $[x_0 : x_1 : \cdots : x_n] \mapsto \left(\frac{x_1}{x_0}, \ldots, \frac{x_n}{x_0}\right)$ is not defined on the hyperplane $x_0 = 0$. So the composition $f \circ p_j$ isn't regular, either, so it need not be constant.

Comment: @André3000, ufff, thanks!!! You are perfectly right.